# WiFi-Hotspot file sharing

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have finished my SQLite database for my application. Now I have to send my .db file to another device and retrieve data from the received database. I have to transfer my file via WIfi-Hotspot. I need a Code to transfer and receive data in my application. So that I can show received data in text view of my another screen in my application. Can any one help me to solve this..I need a code to transfer,receive and retrieve data from the data base.

Comment: Not sure what your actual problem is. You want someone to write you a file-transfer program?

Comment: `I have to transfer my file via WIfi-Hotspot`. Why? Much easier to copy file to pc and then from pc to other device.

Comment: No i searched for tutorial for that..But i didn't get any thing.I need a procedure or code anything...I don't know how to transfer..that's why i am asking code for that..If i has a code i will understand how to transfer.I am new to android.